# Extract a part of URL - python

Tags: python, regex, url, python-2.7

I have an URL  for example:

```
http://name.abc.wxyz:1234/Assts/asset.epx?id=F3F94D94-7232-4FA2-98EF-07sdfssfdsa3B5
```

From this Url I want to extract only '`asset.epx?id=F3F94D94-7232-4FA2-98EF-07sdfssfdsa3B5`' how could i do that?

I am still learning regular expressions and I am not able to solve the above. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Just for this url or there are others?

Comment: Is `asset.epx` always the same?

Comment: @Haidro as per the data i have it is always the same!! but i think solved the issue..Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this specific example splitting the string is enough:

```
url.split('/')[-1]
```

If you have a more complex URL I would recommend the [yarl library](https://github.com/aio-libs/yarl) for parsing it:

```
>>> import yarl  # pip install yarl
>>> url = yarl.URL('http://name.abc.wxyz:1234/Assts/asset.epx?id=F3F94D94-7232-4FA2-98EF-07sdfssfdsa3B5')
>>> url.path_qs
'/Assts/asset.epx?id=F3F94D94-7232-4FA2-98EF-07sdfssfdsa3B5'
```

You could also use the builtin `urllib.parse` library but I find that it gets in the way once you start doing complex things like:

```
>>> url.update_query(asd='foo').with_fragment('asd/foo/bar')
URL('http://name.abc.wxyz:1234/Assts/asset.epx?id=F3F94D94-7232-4FA2-98EF-07sdfssfdsa3B5&asd=foo#asd/foo/bar')
```

Comment: @Blender what if i had to extract only the id from it for example 'F3F94D94-7232-4FA2-98EF-07sdfssfdsa3B5'. HOw do i implement it by regular expression?

Comment: You don't need to use a regular expression. Implementing your own code to interact with standards when modules in the standard library exist is often a bad idea. The urlparse module has functions for turning a query string into a dictionary or a list of key-value pairs.

Comment: Well, this answer has an issue. It is not a generic solution for many urls. Assume, the query string (the part after?) or even the part after # can contain forward slashes. Your solution will still split by it, returning the wrong answer.

Comment: This is a bad solution to getting parts of a URL. The urlparse library as mentioned by @TerryA is what should be used.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) assuming `asset.epx` is the same:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> url = 'http://name.abc.wxyz:1234/Assts/asset.epx?id=F3F94D94-7232-4FA2-98EF-07sdfssfdsa3B5'
>>> res = urlparse.urlparse(url)
>>> print 'asset.epx?'+res.query
asset.epx?id=F3F94D94-7232-4FA2-98EF-07sdfssfdsa3B5
```

This is useful if you ever need other information from the url (You can `print res` to check out the other info you can get ;))

If you're using Python 3 though, you'll have to do `from urllib.parse import urlparse`.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the version of Python, you want either `urlparse` in Python 2.x (http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) or `urllib.parse` in Python 3.x (http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html).  In Python 3 (all I have available), the following snippet achieves what you need without resorting to regular expressions:

```
import urllib.parse

address = "http://name.abc.wxyz:1234/Assts/asset.epx?id=F3F94D94-7232-4FA2-98EF-07sdfssfdsa3B5"
parsed = urllib.parse.urlsplit(address)
print("{}?{}".format(parsed.path.split("/")[-1], parsed.query)
```

The output is "asset.epx?id=F3F94D94-7232-4FA2-98EF-07sdfssfdsa3B5" here.

Comment: @SangameshHs If Brett's answer was what solved your problem, and this post reaches you, you should accept the vote as answering your question. It's the StackOverflow way :]

Comment: @jdero Brett's answer is 100% correct but Blender answered it first and when i click on accept answer it saysi have to wait 5 mins to accept the answer. So, now i did it!! cheers