# Extract the last element of multiple urls in a line

Tags: python, regex, url

I have unstructured data in the following template:

```
'<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1> <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P31c> <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1454986> .',
'<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1> <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P227c> "4079154-3" .',
'<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1> <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P373c> "Universe" .'
```

I want to extract the last element of each url and the result should look like this:

```
'Q1 P31c Q1454986', 
'Q1 P227c 4079154-3', 
'Q1 P373c Universe'
```

I already tried some examples including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253803/how-to-get-everything-after-last-slash-in-a-url) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695662/extract-a-part-of-url-python). But, mostly they only have one link in a line.

I am still learning regular expressions and I am not able to solve the above.

Comment: Why regexes specifically? There's easier ways to do this

Comment: `' '.join(re.findall(r'/([^/>]+)>', s))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not always you have to use regex to get data.

Code is longer then with regex but it can be easier to understand it - so it can be easier to write it.

```
data = [
  '<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1> <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P31c>  <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1454986> .',
  '<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1> <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P227c> "4079154-3" .',
  '<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1> <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P373c> "Universe" .'
]

for line in data:  # get lines
    result = []
    for item in line.split()[:3]:        # split line in items and skip last of them
        if item.startswith('<'):         # method for links
            item = item[1:-1]            # skip < >
            item = item.rsplit('/')[-1]  # get last element
        else:                            # method for not links
            item = item[1:-1]            # skip " "
        result.append(item)              # put on list
    print(' '.join(result))              # concatenate in one string
```

Answer (score 0):

You want 2 group one between `/` and `>`,  and one between two `"`

```
/([^/>]+)>|\"([^\"]+)\"
```